# mapbox styledata event fire 3 times, I only need fire 1 time, how?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

mapbox styledata event fire 3 times, I only need fire 1 time, how?

```
 map.on("styledata", loadTiles);    // will fire multiple 3 times, whenever style changed.  
                                    // event.stopPropagation(); does not work.


 map.on("load", loadTiles);       // only fire 1 time. but when you change base map, use below

      map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/' + layerId, {diff: false});

 //  on load event will not fire, which I need it fire to re-load geojson layer. 


 map.on("styledata"    // works fine, but it fire 3 same event at same time, cause load 3 times geojson layer, cause other error when you load 3 times geojson layer at same time.


    //   How to make styledata on fire 1 times instead of 3?
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the following combination of events to be useful to only fire 1 instead of 3 styledata event :

```
map.on('styledataloading', function() {
    console.log('A styledataloading event occurred.');
    map.once('styledata', function() {
        console.log('A styledata event occurred.');
        loadTiles();
    });
});
```

**Explanation:**

The first event (styledataloading) fires when the map's style starts to change.

> styledataloading: Fired when the map's style begins loading or changing asyncronously. All styledataloading events are followed by a styledata or error event.

As callback you can set up an event listener that only fires for the first styldata event using the map.once(...).

> Once: Adds a listener that will be called only once to a specified event type.
> The listener will be called first time the event fires after the listener is registered.

This way you don't loose the event listener for stylechanges after the first change as you would if you just use `map.once('styledata', loadTiles);`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer in 2019 is:

map.once('styledata', loadTiles);   //The listener will be called first time the event fires after the listener is registered.

```
      map.once('styledata', loadTiles);   //The listener will be called first time the event fires after the listener is registered.


     map.on("styledata", loadTiles);    // will fire multiple 3 times, whenever style changed.  
                                // event.stopPropagation(); does not work.


     map.on("load", loadTiles);       // only fire 1 time. but when you change base map, use below

  map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/' + layerId, {diff: false});

    //  on load event will not fire, which I need it fire to re-load geojson layer. 


       map.on("styledata"    // works fine, but it fire 3 same event at same time, cause load 3 times geojson layer, cause other error when you load 3 times geojson layer at same time.
```